# Reordering data table rows based on value in one column

Tags: datatable, c#-2.0

I have a data table with one column called "position". There can be no duplicates. I want to be able to reorder the rows if the value of this column is changed. For example,

```
**Name    Column2   Position**
Name1    value1      1
Name2    Value2      2
Name3    Value3      3
Name4    Value4      4
Name5    Value5      5
```

If I change the position number 3 to 1, then the table would look like:

```
**Name    Column2   Position**
Name3    Value3      1
Name1    value1      2
Name2    Value2      3
Name4    Value4      4
Name5    Value5      5
```

If I change the position number 3 to 5, in original data table, then:

```
**Name    Column2   Position**
Name1    value1      1
Name2    Value2      2
Name4    Value4      3
Name5    Value5      4
Name3    Value3      5
```

(kind of like NetFlix, when you reorder your movie list)

Answer (score 0):

The question is long ago but maybe this could help someone who has the same problem.

```
//Create a DataView from your table.
 DataView view = new DataView(YourTable);

// Sort by Position column
  view.Sort = "Position ASC";

//and get your new table 
newTable = view.ToTable;

// or you just use the DataView for diplaying your values
```